# Insert text in .txt file using cmd

Tags: linux, text, cmd

So, I want to insert test in .txt but when I try
`type file1.txt >> file2.txt`
and sort it using [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) with `sort file1 | uniq >> sorted` it will place it at the end of the file. But i want to write it to the start of the file. I don't know if this is possible in cmd and if it's not I can also do it in a linux terminal. 
Is there a special flag or operator I need to use?

Thanks in regards, Davin

edit: the file itself (the file i'm writing to) is about 5GB big so i would have to write 5GB to a file every time i wanted to change anything

Comment: changing anything in a text file (except appending to the very end) requires the whole file to be rewritten. There is no way around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to write to the start of the file. You can only replace the file content with content provided or append to the end of a file. So if you need to add the sorted output in front of the `sorted` file, you have to do it like that:

```
mv sorted sorted.old
sort file1 | uniq > sorted
cat sorted.old >> sorted
rm sorted.old
```

This is not a limitation of the shell but of the file APIs of pretty much every existing operating system. The size of a file can only be changed at the end, so you can increase it, in that case the file will grow at the end (all content stays as it is but now there is empty space after the content) or you can truncate it (in that case content is cut off at the end). It is possible to copy data around within a file but there exists no system function to do that, you have to do it yourself and this is almost as inefficient as the solution shown above.

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to put this in my question: the file itself (the file i'm writing to) is about 5GB big so i would have to write 5GB to a file every time i wanted to change anything, editing it right now